# How to Replace multiple string on a TexView for SpannableStrings?

Tags: android, replace, textview, spannablestring

I am looking for a way to find different strings on a TextView and replace them with styled SpannableStrings.

I found this code in [How to use SpannableString with Regex in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364119/how-to-use-spannablestring-with-regex-in-android) that does just that for a single string:

```
public class SpanTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String dispStr = "This has the string ABCDEF in it \nSo does this :ABCDEF - see!\nAnd again ABCD here";
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(dispStr);
        changeTextinView(tv, "ABC", Color.RED);
    }

    private void changeTextinView(TextView tv, String target, int colour) {
        String vString = (String) tv.getText();
        int startSpan = 0, endSpan = 0;
        Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(vString);

        while (true) {
            startSpan = vString.indexOf(target, endSpan);
            ForegroundColorSpan foreColour = new ForegroundColorSpan(colour);
            // Need a NEW span object every loop, else it just moves the span
            if (startSpan < 0)
                break;
            endSpan = startSpan + target.length();
            spanRange.setSpan(foreColour, startSpan, endSpan,
                    Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        tv.setText(spanRange);
    }

}
```

This works great but I'm not sure how to adapt it to use if with multiple strings.
I tried to re-implement it using SpannableStringBuilder.replace so I can run the method multiple times while keeping the previous style but have failed.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works great but I'm not sure how to adapt it to use if with multiple strings.

Off the cuff...

Step #1: Change `changeTextinView()` to take a `SpannableString` as the first parameter, instead of a `TextView`.

Step #2: Modify `onCreate()` to create a `SpannableString` from `dispStr` and pass that to `changeTextinView()`, then take the `SpannableString` and pass it to `setText()` on the `TextView`.

At this point, it should work as it did before, except that you will be in position to do:

Step #3: Call `changeTextinView()` several times in succession, once per string.

Things will get somewhat messy if there is overlap (e.g., you want to format `ABCDEF` one way and `CDE` another way), but I am hoping that is not the case for you.

Comment: Excellent, very simple. Thanks!