# How do I retrieve from a Parcel a CharSequence that was saved using TextUtils.writeToParcel(...)?

Tags: android, parcelable

I want to be able to send formatted text (i.e., text with format spans) from one of my app activities to another. These `CharSequence` instances live deep inside some `Parcelable` types that I created.

For instance, when marshalling one of the types that carries formatted `CharSequence`s I use `TextUtils.writeToParcel` as follows:

```
public class HoldsCharSequence {

    /* some formatted string that uses basic spans (e.g., ForegroundColorSpan) */
    private CharSequence cs;

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        TextUtils.writeToParcel(cs, out, 0);
    }

    /* ... rest of the code ... */
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the `CharSequence` from the `Parcel` in my private constructor.

The following does **not** work:

```
private HoldsCharSequence(Parcel in) {
    cs = (CharSequence) in.readValue(CharSequence.class.getClassLoader());
}
```

I get the following error:

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling
```

Two more things:
 1. I have already succesfully implemented my own custom `Parcelable` objects, the problem is with `CharSequence`s in particular.
 2. I know that `TextUtils.writeToParcel` will do a best-effort job at saving the text format, I can live with that.

Comment: Try cs = in.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());

Comment: @yorkw, your approach yields the same result (`ClassNotFoundException`).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In case someone else is interested, I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338697/android-development-how-to-replace-part-of-an-edittext-with-a-spannable).

The correct way to retrieve `CharSequence`s that were stored in a `Parcel` using `TextUtils.writeToParcel(...)` is

```
cs = TextUtils.CHAR_SEQUENCE_CREATOR.createFromParcel(in);
```