# Is spanning of texts inside EditText possible?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have looked high and possibly low to find this solution but it still doesn't seem to work. I keep looking for a solution but all i can find on google is " how to span TextViews"

Additional notes I have tried the following 
[Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)
[Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)
[Android: Coloring part of a string using TextView.setText()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897349/android-coloring-part-of-a-string-using-textview-settext)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338697/android-development-how-to-replace-part-of-an-edittext-with-a-spannable

Comment: you dont "span" `TextView`s, you "span" `android.text.Spannable`s, BTW `EditText` is a `TextView` (it extends that class)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What you can do is you can use `TextWatcher` and when ever text is changed apply your spannable thing and set it in `EditText`. And as `EditText` is subclass of `TextView`, so , its possible.

Comment: @pskink interesting, Thanks for the insight :)

Comment: @bigdestroyer will check it out in a bit Thank you